# Drawing a Gradient Shape on Canvas

Tags: android, xml, android-canvas

It is easy to draw a rectangle with 1 basic color on a canvas. However, I need to be able to draw a shape with a gradient that starts with one color and evenly shifts to another.

I'm used to drawing backgrounds with gradients by using xml files. Is there a way to reference an xml file when drawing a shape to the canvas? Or is there a better way to draw a gradient shape?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape>
                     <!--  Gradient Bg for Button -->
                     <gradient
                          android:startColor="@color/button_type1_pushed"
                          android:endColor="@color/button_type1_pushed"
                          android:angle="270" />
                     <stroke
                          android:width="0.05dp"
                          android:color="@color/button_type1_border"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

    <item android:state_enabled="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <gradient
                         android:startColor="@color/button_type1_normal"
                         android:endColor="@color/button_type1_normal"
                         android:angle="90" />
                    <stroke
                         android:width="0.05dp"
                         android:color="@color/button_type1_border"/>    
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a shader in your paint element as LinearGradient and then draw a rectangle in the canvas.

You can have horizontal and vertical gradients by the way you draw the rectangle.

You can see a code example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999839/horizontal-lineargradient-with-android)

Answer (score 1):

You can load the xml into a `Drawable` and have that draw on the canvas:

```
Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_drawable);
drawable.draw(canvas);
```

See details at [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable%28int%29).